# How to Nullable.GetUnderlyingType without hitting possible null reference issues

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I'm trying to modernise an old library to support nullable reference type.

This bit is proving challenging. I want to get the type of an object. If it's a nullable type, then I want the underlying type..

```
Type optionalType = //(a type that could be anything, including nullable types.)

if (optionalType.IsGenericType && optionalType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
{
    optionalType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(optionalType);
}
```

This is not happy because `GetUnderlyingType` will return null if you pass it a non-nullable. Compiler shows error `CS8600: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.` But I've already guarded against that.

Is there a way to do this better, or do I have to allow nulls on my `optionalType`?

Comment: Your condition duplicates the exact checks that `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` does. The whole `if` statement/block can be replaced with this: `optionalType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(optionalType) ?? optionalType;`  That is, if `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` returns null, fall back to the value you already have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the source code of `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`, you'll notice that it does the same checks you are doing. In fact it's doing more:

```
     public static Type GetUnderlyingType(Type nullableType) {
        if((object)nullableType == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("nullableType");
        }
        Contract.EndContractBlock();
        Type result = null;
        if( nullableType.IsGenericType && !nullableType.IsGenericTypeDefinition) { 
            // instantiated generic type only                
            Type genericType = nullableType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
            if( Object.ReferenceEquals(genericType, typeof(Nullable<>))) {
                result = nullableType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

As @madreflection says, you can replace that entire chunk of code with simply:

```
optionalType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(optionalType) ?? optionalType;
```